# Prevent WaitForSingleObject from hanging on a named semaphore when other process is terminated?

Tags: winapi, synchronization, semaphore, data-synchronization

When using a globally named mutex to synchronize across two processes, and one of the two processes are killed (say in Task Manager, or due to a fault), the other process returns from `WaitForSingleObject()` with the appropriate error code and can continue.

When using a globally name semaphore, it does not release the waiting process if the other process is killed / terminated.  `WaitForSingleObject()` will wait until it times out (which may be `INFINITE` or hours).

How do I stop `WaitForSingleObject()` from waiting when the other process is killed or terminated?

In this case, there is a single count on the semaphore used to control read/write requests of a shared buffer.  The Requester signals the Provider to provide certain data, the Provider updates the buffer and signals back to the Requester that it can now read the buffer.

Comment: the semaphore not the best object for this. usually named pipe for this used. or (a)lpc. or rpc on more high level

Comment: it's the same application talking to itself.  not really always a server or client but both.  I recall some security issues with named pipe or was it name pipes being disabled (but that may have been across machines not on the same machine?).

Comment: I would not use a semaphore for this, but rather would use named [event objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) instead. One event to signal when data is needed, and one event to signal when data is available. The Requester signals the 1st event, waits on the 2nd event, consumes the data, and resets the 2nd event. The Producer waits on the 1st event, produces the data, resets the 1st event, and signals the 2nd event.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I almost used event objects but already had a semaphore implementation and wanted to catch edge cases where multiple processes running and may all try accessing the data at the same time.  I guess I could perhaps use an auto-reset event to help with that and maybe have to use a mutex as well?

Comment: Also is an event handle going to have the same issue as a semaphore where killing a process can leave it waiting forever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you switch to using WaitForMultipleObjects and wait for the handle of the process that might get terminated (or thread if you want to do this within a single process) in addition to your semaphore handle. That way you can continue to use INFINITE timeouts. Just have to check the return value to see which object was signalled.

Also, I would consider a process terminating while holding a semaphore somewhat of a bug, particularly a semaphore used for actual inter-process communication.

Comment: I was thinking I'm going to need that process handle and check it, good idea to use it with WaitforMultipleObjects (I stupidly was thinking of looping with a check).  The problem is the two processes may be in different spaces, which is actually why this is even needed, one in the background (started via Task Scheduler) and then one in foreground to figure-out where it's at.  How do I get that handle of the other process?  It's holding a named mutex (which is how I can tell it's running) if I can get it from that?

Comment: I think I got this, going to do a quick operation sending process id, then for the potential long wait, use the process handle to ensure we don't wait forever if process closed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer.

I added logic if the `waitms` was going to be longer than some value `maxwaitms` then the requester/provider exchange the providers process id (`GetCurrentProcessId()`) before the long process.  The requester opens a handle (`OpenHandle()`) to the provider process and waits on both the semaphore and the process handle to know when writing is done (or process terminated).